# Conic sections: intersection of a plane and a cone. How can I change the equation of the plane to get conic sections automatically?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, regions, intersection

I tried to draw intersection of a plane and a cone.

Hyperbola

```
Clear["Global`*"]
myh = 5;
myr = 4;
pA = {0, 0, myh};
pT = {0, 0, 2*myh};
pO = {0, 0, 0};
cone1 = Cone[{pO, pA}, myr];
cone2 = Cone[{pT, pA}, myr];
plane = InfinitePlane[{{0, -3, 0}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 2}}];
plotcone1 = 
  RegionPlot3D[DiscretizeRegion@RegionIntersection[cone1, plane], 
   BoundaryStyle -> {Thick, Red}, PlotStyle -> None, Boxed -> False, 
   PlotRange -> All];
plotcone2 = 
  RegionPlot3D[DiscretizeRegion@RegionIntersection[cone2, plane], 
   BoundaryStyle -> {Thick, Red}, PlotStyle -> None, Boxed -> False, 
   PlotRange -> All];
Show[plotcone1, plotcone2, 
 Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.8], cone1, cone2, plane}, Boxed -> False]]
```

[image]

Parabola

```
Clear["Global`*"]
myh = 5;
myr = 4;
pA = {0, 0, myh};
pT = {0, 0, 2*myh};
pO = {0, 0, 0};
cone1 = Cone[{pO, pA}, myr];
cone2 = Cone[{pT, pA}, myr];
plane = InfinitePlane[{{0, 2, 0}, {1, 2, -1}, {2, 2, 0}}];
plotcone1 = 
  RegionPlot3D[DiscretizeRegion@RegionIntersection[cone1, plane], 
   BoundaryStyle -> {Thick, Red}, PlotStyle -> None, Boxed -> False, 
   PlotRange -> All];
plotcone2 = 
  RegionPlot3D[DiscretizeRegion@RegionIntersection[cone2, plane], 
   BoundaryStyle -> {Thick, Red}, PlotStyle -> None, Boxed -> False, 
   PlotRange -> All];
Show[plotcone1, plotcone2, 
 Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.8], cone1, cone2, plane}, Boxed -> False]]
```

[image]

I input the `plane = InfinitePlane[{{0, -3, 0}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 2}}];` by hand. How can I input `InfinitePlane` to get conic sections automatically? Can I input `InfinitePlane` in the form `a x + b y + c z + d = 0`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- For any plane equation `{a,b,c}.{x,y,z}=d`, we use `MeshFunction->Function[{x, y, z}, {a, b, c} . {x, y, z} - d` and `Hyperplane[{a,b,c},d]`.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
myh = 5;
myr = 4;
pA = {0, 0, myh};
pT = {0, 0, 2*myh};
pO = {0, 0, 0};
cone1 = Cone[{pO, pA}, myr];
cone2 = Cone[{pT, pA}, myr];
{a, b, c} = RandomPoint[Sphere[]];
d = RandomReal[];
plot3d = 
  RegionPlot3D[{cone1, cone2}, 
   MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y, z}, {a, b, c} . {x, y, z}], 
   Mesh -> {{d}}, MeshStyle -> Directive@{Thick, Red}];
plane = Graphics3D[Hyperplane[{a, b, c}, d]];
Show[plot3d, plane]
```

- Manipulate

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{plot3d, plane}, 
  mesh = RegionPlot3D[{cone1, cone2}, 
    MeshFunctions -> Function[{x, y, z}, {a, b, c} . {x, y, z}], 
    Mesh -> {{d}}, MeshStyle -> Directive@{Thick, Red}, 
    PlotStyle -> Transparent];
  g3d = Graphics3D[{cone1, cone2, Hyperplane[{a, b, c}, d]}];
  Show[g3d, mesh, 
   PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic, {0, 10}}]], {a, -1, 1}, {b, -1,
   1}, {c, -1, 1}, {d, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT**: I've rewritten pre-existing code significantly in addition to `ImplicitRegion` tricks below.

First of all using `RegionPlot3D` with discretized regions works... mostly by sheer luck. It's not really designed for that.

My personal approach to this is to discretize the intersection of the boundary of the cone with the plane, extract `Line` components from it... and show all this as plain `Graphics3D` content.

The problem you ran into while attempting to show intersection which intersects with only one of the two cones is, if you ask me, both a bug and a design issue in Mathematica: it can't really discretize an empty region since it can't express an $n$-dimensional empty mesh region! So, my workaround checks if the region to be discretized is actually empty, and instead of discretizing it if this is the case, just adds `Nothing` (that is, no entry) to the list of `Graphics3D` primitives.

---

I don't really know what you mean by "how can I input InfinitePlane to get conic sections automatically" but below is a solution to your second question.

You can use `ImplicitRegion`. The issue here is, though, that `ImplicitRegion` isn't a graphics primitive.

First of all, an `ImplicitRegion` can be generated using `RegionConvert`:

```
RegionConvert[InfinitePlane[{{0, -3, 0}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 2}}], "Implicit"]

(* ImplicitRegion[
    2 \[FormalX] + \[FormalZ] == 3 + \[FormalY], {\[FormalX], \[FormalY], \[FormalZ]}] *)
```

If you want to convert this implicit region back to an `InfinitePlane`, you have another problem. We can pick three points from the plane and reconstruct it from them, but `RandomPoint` doesn't work because you can't really take a uniform sample from an infinite plane. We can use `FindInstance`, though.

The code below represents the implicit plane equation as `iplane`, and derives the graphics primitive `plane` from it:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
myh = 5;
myr = 4;
pA = {0, 0, myh};
pT = {0, 0, 2 myh};
pO = {0, 0, 0};
cone1 = Cone[{pO, pA}, myr];
cone2 = Cone[{pT, pA}, myr];
iplane = ImplicitRegion[2 x - y + z - 3 == 0, {x, y, z}];
plane = InfinitePlane[{x, y, z} /. 
    FindInstance[RegionMember[iplane, {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}, 3]];
Graphics3D[{{Red, Thick, 
   With[{r = RegionIntersection[RegionBoundary[#], iplane]}, 
      If[RegionEqual[r, EmptyRegion[3]], Nothing, 
       MeshPrimitives[DiscretizeRegion[r, Method -> "Semialgebraic"], 
        1]]] & /@ {cone1, cone2}}, {Opacity[0.8], cone1, cone2, 
   plane}}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: I tried `iplane = ImplicitRegion[x + z + y - 3 == 0, {x, y, z}];` or `iplane = ImplicitRegion[x- 3 == 0, {x, y, z}];` I can not get result.

Comment: I've modified my answer significantly, please check if it works for you (it does for me.)

Comment: Thanks. Sometimes, the plane cut only one cone. E,g. `iplane = ImplicitRegion[ z - 3 == 0, {x, y, z}];` or `iplane = ImplicitRegion[ 3  x  +  z - 3 == 0, {x, y, z}];` Please consider this cases.

Comment: Sigh... the `EmptyRegion` test was supposed to fix this, but it seems your examples run into a kink that is discretizing single-dimensional regions in three dimensions. The situation can be improved with addition of `Method -> "Semialgebraic"` on `DiscretizeRegion`, which solves your second example. Sadly it doesn't solve the first one, but on basis of bug feedback I've received from WRI rather recently, `"Semialgebraic"` method has seen improvements and this is going to be fixed in a version not so far in the future.

Comment: Thank you very much.